# Multiple midi CC# on one single knob

Tags: ableton-live

I have an issue with my Yamaha DX200 and Ableton midi, I spent hours looking on internet and trying to find a way, but nothing worked.

So I basically want to control the DX200 as a soundmodule on Ableton.
What I do is program a pattern on the DX200, then on Ableton I build my track by arranging the pattern by drawing automations (filter, attack, decay etc.)

I have been able to map all the knobs on Ableton, each knobs have only one midi CC# except those from the Modulator section - that we can see on those screens

https://image.ibb.co/emRgVn/DX2.jpg

https://i.pi.gy/Bq9ej.png

The buttons "Harmonic", "FM Depth" and "Decay" have three midi CC# dedicated to each of their knob. So for example if I want to draw an automation of the "Harmonic" button, I have to draw it three times, because the three CC# have to be mapped on three differents macro on Ableton (can't map multiple CC# on one single knob - it automatically replace the last one)

https://image.ibb.co/g1R9i7/DX1.jpg

https://image.ibb.co/myMv5n/DX.jpg

It work, but the problem is that it's not convenient at all. I would like to have one single knob that can control those three different CC#.

Does anyone know a way to do that?

Thanks

M.

Comment: This kind of thing is pretty simple in Cubase, using the transform page on the input, with a list of simultaneous non-destructive transforms. I don't know if Ableton has anything similar. Googling only brings up midi to audio, so maybe not.

Comment: Google didn't give me any answer neither :-/
Anyone here know how to do that? 
It's probably simple.

Comment: There's always the convoluted option of getting one of the bottom-end Cubase versions, use the Transformer, then IAC or Rewire that across to the rest of your environment...

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find [this page](http://djtechtools.com/2012/02/16/mapulator-advanced-midi-mapping-for-ableton/) of interest. It's a tool called "Mapulator," which I have not yet used, but which looks like precisely what you're looking for and more, although you would have to draw the same curve multiple times from the looks of it. It also hasn't been updated in a while, evidently.

There's also [Multi-parameter Curves](http://www.maxforlive.com/library/device/4172/multi-parameter-curves), which is meant to be a sort of successor to Mapulator.

You'll need Max for Live to use either, though. To add it to Ableton 9 will set you back US$199. Before pulling the trigger on that purchase, keep in mind that Max for Live is built into Ableton Live 10, rather than being a separate purchase.

I hope that helps. :)